# to create zip of files on remote server in perl

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl and trying to create a zip file. The files, the script both are in same directory and the zip also needs to be there only. Below is the code am trying and it is exiting without any error but without any zip file also. I am passing "*.txt" as the command line argument. Kindly suggest.

```
use strict;
use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

die "usage: $0 zip.pl\n"
  if (scalar(@ARGV) < 1);

my $zipName = "dummy";
my $zip     = Archive::Zip->new();

foreach my $memberName (map { glob} @ARGV ) {
    if (-d $memberName) {
        warn "Can't add tree $memberName\n"
          if $zip->addTree($memberName, $memberName) != AZ_OK;
    } else {
        $zip->addFile($memberName)
          or warn "Can't add file $memberName\n";
    }
}

my $status = $zip->writeToFileNamed($zipName);
exit $status;
```

Comment: Working on Linux, *may be* on Windows extension matters try  `$zipName = "dummy.zip"` and check if it works.

Comment: M working on windows, tried using ".zip" in name, no help. Also please see i am passing *.txt as argument , and i have abc.txt, xyz.txt files present on the location. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you passsing it in double quotes as `*` is special character, or once change your `map { glob} @ARGV` to only `glob "*.txt"` and verify.

Comment: tried both passing argument in double quotes and glob "*.txt". None helped. Anything else we can do?

Comment: I don't see a `chdir` in your code. Is your working directory the same as where the files live? In other words, have you added a `print "$memberName\n";` to the beginning of your `for` loop to verify that you're actually iterating over something?

Comment: I tried another peice of code, this also not giving any error but just not generating output.

Answer (score -1):

The site(ARGS) method is designed for that. You can send a shell command and make it runs on remote server. http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html#METHODS

Comment: I need these files to  be zipped on Windows remote server.

Comment: Can any one suggest what could be the issue here.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant.